# Is a SQLAlchemy query vulnerable to injection attacks?

Tags: python, security, flask, sql-injection, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following query that uses `like` to search a blog.  I am not sure if I'm making myself vulnerable to a SQL injection attack if I do this.  How is SQLAlchemy handling this?  Is it safe?

```
search_results = Blog.query.with_entities(Blog.blog_title).filter(Blog.blog_title.like("%"+ searchQuery['queryText'] +"%")).all()
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The underlying db-api library for whatever database you're using (sqlite3, psycopg2, etc.) escapes parameters.  SQLAlchemy simply passes the statement and parameters to [`execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15), the driver does whatever is needed.  Assuming you are not writing raw SQL that includes parameters yourself, you are not vulnerable to injection.  Your example is not vulnerable to injection.