# Is SQLAlchemy safe from SQL injection?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Simple question, but I just want to be sure of the answer: using Flask-SQLAlchemy, is this safe (where searchstring comes directly from the user?)

```
results = MyClass.query.filter(MyClass.MyProperty.ilike('%{}%'.format(searchstring)))
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy is good but you should avoid raw SQL as much as possible. In your case it does not look that it is prone to SQL Injection but my 2 cents is to avoid raw SQl as much as possible.

Also refer: [Is a SQLAlchemy query vulnerable to injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949733/is-a-sqlalchemy-query-vulnerable-to-injection-attacks)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a simple value that I can pass in to searchstring to confirm that?